# Programmatically created UIButton not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit

I have created a `UIButton`, added it to a view, which has then been added to a `UIScrollView`. This View also contains a `UITextView` which displays and is formatted correctly.

My code is below. Hopefully someone can help. The area where the button should be is clickable, and acts correctly, however the button is not visible. I even changed the tintColor to red, but I cannot see it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

UIView *billBlocker = *UIView initialized*
//The UITextView is a subview of `billBlocker`, as well as the `billBlockButton`
//added the UITextView here


UIButton *billBlockButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5,292,30 )];


    [billBlockButton setTitle:@"BillBlockerFrenzy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [billBlockButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [billBlockButton addTarget:self action:@selector(segueToRegulationsGame) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];




    [billBlocker addSubview:billBlockButton];





    [self.scrollView addSubview:billBlocker];
}
```

Comment: I'd miss such a line: `[self.scrollView addSubview:billBlockButton]`, regarding you have forgot the clarify what `billBlocker` is and how it was inited.

Comment: you NEVER EVER init a UIButton with initWithFrame. UIButton inherits from NSControl not from UIView, so you dont have initWithFrame

Comment: Can I ask a somewhat related question here? I don't know what I'm doing wrong with StackOverflow questions. I don't understand why this questions was voted down. Could you explain what I should do to ask my questions properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use cluster method when crate button:

```
UIButton *billBlockButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[billBlockButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5,292,30 )];
...
```

This code should work. Make sure the scrollView frame and content size is set correctly and scrollView is added to self.view.

buttonWithType: is recommended method for creating the button, this is the only way you can specify button type.
When you use alloc init, I believe, you use some standard button type and if iOS change the standard also could change.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Could you please explain why? I don't understand why my method does not work.

Comment: I'm guessing your method did work, but you couldn't see the button. The only difference with the above is that this code specifies the rounded rect button - which has an outline. You could try your original code with setting the button background colour to red - and that will probably show it

Comment: @iBhavin I had to wait for some time, it did not allow me to accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is you forgot the set outlet of scroll view i tried and its working like this

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *sView; //scrollviews outlet
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];



//added the UITextView here


UIButton *billBlockButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5,292,30 )];


[billBlockButton setTitle:@"BillBlockerFrenzy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[billBlockButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[billBlockButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nothing)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



[self.sView addSubview:billBlockButton];
}
```

Forgot to say you need to add your method instead of nothing method..
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

When we create the UIButton object programmatically, the default title color of UIButton is white.

So, set the title color of UIButton object.

```
[billBlockButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 or later will have transparent button. Unless you set text, you will not be able to see. Do following:

```
[[yourButton layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[[yourButton layer] setBorderWidth:2.0];
[yourButton setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```